# For Loop Auto Arima by customer

Tags: r, loops, arima

I am collaborating on a project that requires me to use R of which I don't have any experience with to date. I am trying to apply auto arima to partitions/windows within my dataset and I haven't the slightest clue on how to even begin.

Essentially, I want to train a separate model on each partner_id using the rows c_id = "none" and then forecast/predict values out to the max(date) for each partner_id. The number of months/rows for each partner vary in length. For this example data frame pasted below, partner_id = "1A9" has 12 months/rows with c_id = "none" vs partner_id = "1B9" has 13 months/row with c_id = "none". The number of months/rows extended out to the max(Date) within each partner_id varies as well. I essentially want to join my predictions and possibly prediction intervals back to my original dataframe.

I've started some code but I keep getting an error 'Error in if (frequency > 1 && 0 < (d <- abs(frequency - round(frequency))) && : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed'. It seems to be choking when I attempt to train the Auto Arima. My code so far is

```
predictions_df <- data.frame(c_id = character(),
                         partner_id = character(),
                         rev_month = character(),
                         rev = double())

partners <- unique(df$partner_id) 

for (i in 1:length(partners)) {
 x1 <- df[df$partner_id %in% partners, ] # likely redundant since I
 x1_train <- x1[x1$c_id == "No-Contract", c(3, 4)] # training data
 x1_test <- x1[x1$c_id != "No-Contract", c(3, 4)] # forecast data
 c_int <- x1[x1$c_id != "No-Contract", 1] # confidence interval data?

# convert training data to time-series object
x1_train_ts <- xts::xts(x1_train$rev, order.by=x1_train$rev_month)
# run auto arima on the time series
tm <- forecast::auto.arima(x1_train_ts, approximation = FALSE, biasadj = TRUE, stepwise = FALSE)
# forecast the number of future steps (rows for to predict data)
fc <- forecast::forecast(tm, nrow(x1_test))

# append predictions back to dataframe
predictions_df <- rbind(predictions_df, data.frame(ar_name, partner_id, rev_month = as.character(x1_test$rev_month),   rev = as.double(fc$mean)))
```

I've included a sample dataset and my code below.

```
test <- data.frame("c_id" = c("none","none","none","none","none",
"none","none","none","none","none","none","none","c-100","c-100","c-100","c-100","c-100","c-100","c-100","c-100","c-100","c-100","c-100","c-100","c-101","c-101","c-101","c-101","c-101","c-101","c-101","c-101","c-101","c-101","c-101","c-101","c-101", "none","none","none","none","none","none","none","none","none","none","none","none","none","c-110","c-110","c-110","c-110","c-110","c-110","c-110","c-110","c-110","c-110","c-110","c-110","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111"), "partner_id" = c("1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9"), "rev_month" = as.Date(c("2015-12-01","2016-01-01","2016-02-01","2016-03-01","2016-04-01","2016-05-01","2016-06-01","2016-07-01","2016-08-01", "2016-09-01","2016-10-01","2016-11-01","2016-12-01","2017-01-01","2017-02-01","2017-03-01","2017-04-01","2017-05-01","2017-06-01","2017-07-01","2017-08-01","2017-09-01","2017-10-01","2017-11-01","2017-12-01","2018-01-01","2018-02-01","2018-03-01","2018-04-01","2018-05-01","2018-06-01","2018-07-01","2018-08-01","2018-09-01","2018-10-01","2018-11-01","2018-12-01", "2017-01-01","2017-01-01","2017-02-01","2017-03-01","2017-04-01","2017-05-01","2017-06-01","2017-07-01","2017-08-01", "2017-09-01","2017-10-01","2017-11-01","2017-12-01","2018-01-01","2018-02-01","2018-03-01","2018-04-01","2018-05-01","2018-06-01","2018-07-01","2018-08-01","2018-09-01","2018-10-01","2018-11-01","2018-12-01","2019-01-01","2019-02-01","2019-03-01","2019-04-01","2019-05-01","2019-06-01","2019-07-01","2019-08-01","2019-09-01","2019-10-01","2019-11-01","2019-12-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01")), "rev" = c(101.25, 102.25, 103.50, 103.75, 104.15, 104.25, 104.3, 105.00, 105.20, 105.60, 106.00, 106.10, 106.50, 101.50, 100.30, 107.50, 108.30, 108.45, 109.10, 110.10, 112.15, 112.45, 114.65, 115.00, 116.00, 116.50, 117.25, 117.85, 119.25, 119.95, 120.20, 121.50, 122.30, 122.40, 123.25, 123.75, 124.00, 101.25, 102.25, 103.50, 103.75, 104.15, 104.25, 104.3, 105.00, 105.20, 105.60, 106.00, 106.10, 106.50, 101.50, 100.30, 107.50, 108.30, 108.45, 109.10, 110.10, 112.15, 112.45, 114.65, 115.00, 116.00, 116.50, 117.25, 117.85, 119.25, 119.95, 120.20, 121.50, 122.30, 122.40, 123.25, 123.75, 124.00, 124.10, 125.35, 125.45), stingsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

I am open if there is a better way to write this but I am pretty desperate to get this done today. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Key points to remark:

1. As posted in the code, you got to make sure that your data is clean and is sorted in chronological order for each "partner_id".
2. Remember, if you have a large dataset try to use the default parameters for "auto.arima" function.
3. And also, make sure you have enough data in order to get more robust estimates. For instance, in the sample dataset you have provided, your forecast horizon is larger than your training length.
4. You should be able to compute in-sample and out-of-sample forecast accuracy (RMSE, MAE, MAPE, etc.) in a validation set (if you have enough data, you should divide it between training and validation sets, using a 70-80/30-20 mixture).

Here is my answer:

```
# Load libraries
library(forecast)
library(dplyr)

# Load the dataset - the one you provided for these purposes
c_id <- c("none","none","none","none","none","none","none","none","none","none","none","none","c-100","c-100","c-100","c-100","c-100","c-100","c-100","c-100","c-100","c-100","c-100","c-100","c-101","c-101","c-101","c-101","c-101","c-101","c-101","c-101","c-101","c-101","c-101","c-101","c-101", "none","none","none","none","none","none","none","none","none","none","none","none","none","c-110","c-110","c-110","c-110","c-110","c-110","c-110","c-110","c-110","c-110","c-110","c-110","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111","c-111")
partner_id <- c("1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1A9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9","1B9")
rev_month <- as.Date(c("2015-12-01","2016-01-01","2016-02-01","2016-03-01","2016-04-01","2016-05-01","2016-06-01","2016-07-01","2016-08-01", "2016-09-01","2016-10-01","2016-11-01","2016-12-01","2017-01-01","2017-02-01","2017-03-01","2017-04-01","2017-05-01","2017-06-01","2017-07-01","2017-08-01","2017-09-01","2017-10-01","2017-11-01","2017-12-01","2018-01-01","2018-02-01","2018-03-01","2018-04-01","2018-05-01","2018-06-01","2018-07-01","2018-08-01","2018-09-01","2018-10-01","2018-11-01","2018-12-01", "2017-01-01","2017-01-01","2017-02-01","2017-03-01","2017-04-01","2017-05-01","2017-06-01","2017-07-01","2017-08-01", "2017-09-01","2017-10-01","2017-11-01","2017-12-01","2018-01-01","2018-02-01","2018-03-01","2018-04-01","2018-05-01","2018-06-01","2018-07-01","2018-08-01","2018-09-01","2018-10-01","2018-11-01","2018-12-01","2019-01-01","2019-02-01","2019-03-01","2019-04-01","2019-05-01","2019-06-01","2019-07-01","2019-08-01","2019-09-01","2019-10-01","2019-11-01","2019-12-01", "2020-01-01", "2020-02-01", "2020-03-01"))
rev <- c(101.25, 102.25, 103.50, 103.75, 104.15, 104.25, 104.3, 105.00, 105.20, 105.60, 106.00, 106.10, 106.50, 101.50, 100.30, 107.50, 108.30, 108.45, 109.10, 110.10, 112.15, 112.45, 114.65, 115.00, 116.00, 116.50, 117.25, 117.85, 119.25, 119.95, 120.20, 121.50, 122.30, 122.40, 123.25, 123.75, 124.00, 101.25, 102.25, 103.50, 103.75, 104.15, 104.25, 104.3, 105.00, 105.20, 105.60, 106.00, 106.10, 106.50, 101.50, 100.30, 107.50, 108.30, 108.45, 109.10, 110.10, 112.15, 112.45, 114.65, 115.00, 116.00, 116.50, 117.25, 117.85, 119.25, 119.95, 120.20, 121.50, 122.30, 122.40, 123.25, 123.75, 124.00, 124.10, 125.35, 125.45)
df <- data.frame(c_id, partner_id, rev_month, rev, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# Make sure that your data is sorted in cronological order
df <- 
  df %>% 
  arrange(partner_id, rev_month)
# Create a new column to store the predictions for each model
df$model_predictions <- 0

# Fit an ARIMA model for each partner and get n-steps forecast
partners <- unique(df$partner_id)
for (k in partners) {
  # Keep data for the partner of interest for each iteration
  df_iter <- df[df$partner_id == k,]
  # Get training data
  # Recall that dates don't matter as long as your data is
  # sorted in cronological order and you have one observation per date
  train_data <- df_iter[df_iter$c_id == "none", "rev"]
  # Get number of steps to forecast
  n_ahead <- nrow(df_iter[df_iter$c_id != "none",])
  # Fit the model
  model <-
    auto.arima(train_data, approximation = FALSE, biasadj = TRUE, stepwise = FALSE)
  # Forecast data for the given partner
  fcast <- as.numeric(forecast(model, h = n_ahead, biasadj = TRUE)$mean)
  # Place fitted and forecasted values in the original data frame
  predictions <- c(model$fitted, fcast)
  df[df$partner_id == k, "model_predictions"] <- predictions
}
```